Got different types of error from a single C program in Linux
I am working on an embedded Linux (kernel-5.10.24) and now I am running a C program to do a stress testing about file copying.  The code is using stdio to read and write file, as follows,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef BUF_SIZE        /* Allow "cc -D" to override definition */
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#endif

static unsigned char buf[BUF_SIZE];
static char *infname = "/tmp/src_file.bin";
static char *ofname  = "/tmp/dst_file.bin";

static int create_dest_file(const char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create/truncate %s\n", fname);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

static int copy_file(const char *src, const char *dest)
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    int rlen = 0, wlen = 0, rc = 0;

    // Open one file for reading
    fp = fopen(src, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", src);
        return 1;
    }

    fp2 = fopen(dest, "ab");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        rlen = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
        if (rlen > 0) {
            wlen = fwrite(buf, 1, rlen, fp2);
            if (wlen != rlen) {
                printf("Wrote len: %d, read len: %d\n", wlen, rlen);
                rc = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0, rc = 0;
    int us = 500000;

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s srcfile dstfile delay_in_us\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    infname = argv[1];
    ofname  = argv[2];
    us = atoi(argv[3]);

    printf("Copying %s to %s\n", infname, ofname);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        create_dest_file(ofname);
        rc = copy_file(infname, ofname);
        printf("XXXXXXXXXXX %d, rc: %d\n", i, rc);
        usleep(us);
    }

    return 0;
}

After compile it and run it with ./filecopy /root/16MB_src.bin /root/dest.bin 250000, I would got several different types of error like Segmentation fault, Bus error, Illegal instruction, and so on.
I installed the GDB to run filecopy, and got one following error.
XXXXXXXXXXX 45, rc: 0
XXXXXXXXXXX 46, rc: 0
Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x77cdfd44 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x77cdfd44 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x77c964ac in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x77c97ae4 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
warning: GDB can't find the start of the function at 0x77cd0c97.
#3  0x77cd0c98 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)

I checked the code and asked other colleagues to review the code, no error found :-(.
From the error types, the code triggered same random failures, but I cannot find the root-cause.
The system has 64MB RAM, and the source file is about 18MB, the libc is GLIBC2.38.
With many tests, it is found if the source file is about 1MB, the program ran well, no error hit.
If the source file about 8MB, and 18MB, the program hit errors.
If the file (18MB) is read from NAND and written to RAM, it ran well.
If the file (18MB) is read from RAM and written to NAND, it hit error.
The output of free -k showed
# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          54580       13228        9404         344       31948       38260
Swap:             0           0           0

# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          54580       13252       17480         344       23848       38240
Swap:             0           0           0

# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          54580       13260       11936         344       29384       38232
Swap:             0           0           0

# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          54580       13252        6656         344       34672       38240
Swap:             0           0           0

# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          54580       13244       19304         344       22032       38224

The memory is NOT used up.

Are you running as root?  If not, do you have write access to /root?  Does /root exist?

Yes, /root exists, and I am running the code as root.

Since this appears to be a hardware problem, I'm voting to close as non-reproducible. Maybe a new question about the memory/SoC problem could be posted at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, but in case of SoC I don't think many can help you - you are at the mercy of the silicon manufacturer.

With lots of tests from software, I am suspecting the hardware or the driver (not for sure). The NAND chip was used in other products before and never hit the problems I posted here.  The purpose of my asking this question is to get code reviewed by experts and learn the skills of problem analysis and solving. So far, I got several valuable comments here, but no concrete answers to this question. I would like keep it open for a while for my updating root-cause later.

"I would got several different types of error ..." - A lot more details please. "Error" or a panic?

I haved listed the errors I got in the original question: segmenation fault, Bus error, Illegal instruction, Trace/Breakpoint exception, and system hang (WDT reset system).

Those are just "types" of "errors". I asked for details. You've only provided a vague single-line summation to describe the failures. You need to be more cooperative/accommodating if you expect free help.

These types of errors are what I hit in the tests, and I would like to provide more details if I can, but this problem shows different types of errors randomly and NO concrete clues to point to a root cause. I am not sure how do you conclude I need to be "more cooperative/accomodating" ?

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your program, your problem likely lies elsewhere.

I would got several different types of error like Segmentation fault, Bus error, Illegal instruction, and so on.

All of these could be the result of bad memory (reading back values other than what was written previously).
I suggest running a memory checker program to confirm or rule out this possibility.
You could also run other memory-intensive known stable applications (such as gcc itself) -- if you see crashes in them as well, "bad memory" is a very likely root cause.

What memory checker do you recommend? This is an embedded system, the hardware source is limited. I just did a test to read big file from NAND FLASH and write it to /tmp (RAM), it worked fine, no error hit, the MD5 of the files are the same.  When file is read from /tmp/ (RAM) and written to NAND FLASH, it can hit a certain error. I checked the hardware with vendor, no conclusion so far.... :-(

@wangt13 looks like the error is not with your code.  Either a physical issue with the NAND, or the NAND driver.  Since Amy test is likely to use that driver, you may not be able to determine which.

Sure, from my testing matrix, NAND is suspectible. Now I am checking with SOC vendor on the NAND FLASH and its driver. They told me it may be wrong from RAM or memory management of kernel, but I am not sure about it, since I have tested read from/write to /tmp, no error hit. I would NOT think it is a kernel error.
